# Using StackOverflow (or its engine) for theDailyWTF programming praxis

Tags: discussion, so-engine, third-party

I heard or read somewhere that SO is working with Alex, from theDailyWTF fame. He's running a silly code competition named Programming Praxis. You can find the [lastest one](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Nerds,-Jocks,-and-Lockers.aspx) here. When I see the submissions I automatically look for the upvote button. Since SO and TDWTF are already doing some things together (will supply link when I've found it) is it an idea to host the Programming Praxis on SO?

[EDIT] Is was mentioned in [podcast #64](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/podcast-64/)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure I'd want to see all the code on a single page. What I'd quite like would be posts describing the general algorithm used, with a link to the code in case I want to read the submission in its entirety.

This goes back to a previous idea about SO hosting code snippets etc itself (rather than using pastebin and the like) to avoid dead links. I'm in two minds about that, but I think it would be useful in this particular case.

Comment: strange, I wonder who owns the sopaste.com domain?

Comment: whois says you do, matches codinghorrors whois records ... so I guess the question is rhetorical

Answer (score 1):

An interesting one... if there is some specific coding question (as *part* of the problem), then maybe - and there is certainly no lack of code-golf questions on SO.

However, I *personally* wouldn't want it to be the default - i.e. as soon as tdwtf issues a Praxis, the same question appears on SO, with a large number of replies, and few people actually *reading* them (just posting their own). I can't see the benefit; if people want to enter the Praxis, then do that in tdwtf.

Also; if you *do* ask for help on SO, son't forget appropriate attribution in your Praxis submission ;-p

Answer (score 1):

Actually, a similar question had already been asked on Stack Overflow.

[What is the best solution for the ‘Students and Lockers’ problem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272868/what-is-the-best-solution-for-the-students-and-lockers-problem) (2008-11-07)

With the the [Nerds, Jocks, and Lockers](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Nerds,-Jocks,-and-Lockers.aspx) question, from TD-WTF, being asked about 9 months later. (2009-08-05)

Comment: http://www.cartalk.com/content/puzzler/transcripts/200546/answer.html

Comment: Hey that kinda funny, didn't see the Student and Lockers question